# How to exclude weekends from arshaw calendar(full calendar)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar

I have a question relating to the plugin called full Calendar by Arshaw ?

I have a calendar with events which are coming from data store with the respective Start date and End date.
The problem is that i have to skip the Saturday and Sunday from the duration.
Here is my code:

```
     var obj = '';
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
     /*  weekMode:'liquid', weekends:false, */
         header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },

        events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
        $.get('calendar',function(doc) {
                        var events = [];
                         var data = JSON.parse(doc);
                     obj = data.event;

                     for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++){
                        events.push({
                             title:obj[i].title,
                             start:obj[i].start, //start day
                             end:obj[i].end,// end date
                        });
                   }

                callback(events);
            });
       }



   });  

});
```

I went through the other queries in stack overflow  but I m not able to find out the suitable answer as there is no Drag and Drop events.
If u have any queries about this feel free to ask,any help would be appreciated!

Comment: is there anyone have an answer for this question

Comment: Hi, were you able to find a solution to this question?

Comment: How about weekends:false? http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/weekends/